# Does gnome-terminal modify PATH when invoking shell

Tags: shell, path, gnome-terminal

I guess gnome-terminal might have modified `PATH` environ variable when invoking shell.
Specifically, `$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin` will always be appended to `PATH`.

I did the following experiment to demonstrate this:

- Open a gnome-terminal
- traverse through "Edit" -> "Preference" -> "Profiles" and "Edit" your current profile
  (which is "Unamed" for me)
- Under the "Command" tab, check "Run a custom command instead of my shell" and
  fill in the following input area with `sh`. In this way, `bash` should be called in `sh`-way and it's not a login shell.
- To further make sure the `/etc/profile`, `$HOME/.bash_profile`, `$HOME/.bashrc` doesn't
  get sourced, we rename these files temporarily. (Actually, these files should NOT get
  sourced already, as we are invoking a non-login `sh`.)
- Now, open a new gnome-terminal window and run `echo $PATH`. Here is what I got:

  ```
  /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/naitree/.local/bin:/home/naitree/bin
  ```

I don't understand why the last two path appeared in `PATH`.

Based on this fact, I think the following possible explanations exists:

1. the `PATH` is inherited from parent process, which in this case is the `gnome-terminal-server`.
2. the `PATH` is modifed in some script that is sourced mysteriously by `sh` at some point.
3. the `PATH` is modifed when gnome-terminal-server forks off the subprocess.

Now I think I have ruled out the #1 and the #2 possibilties:

1. `cat /proc/$PPID/environ` where `$PPID` is the PID of `gnome-terminal-server` shows that
   its `PATH` variable is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin`, which does not contain what we are looking for.
2. In the `sh` we have just opened, run `export -n PATH` and `sh -x`, I can see nothing
   get sourced during the init process of this new `sh`. And its `PATH` is clean:

   ```
   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
   ```

Which leaves me the last possibility.

Did I missed something? Is gnome-terminal the culprit for the mysteriously modified `PATH`?

---

Update:

I just tried `sh -x` as the custom command. Upon opening gonme-terminal, I didn't see anything get sourced. But, `echo $PATH` says that `$HOME/.local/bin` and `$HOME/bin` are there.

Here are distro related info:

- Fedora 23 (4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64)
- bash version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

---

Update2:

I just tried:

- Add `echo "$PATH"` at the very beginning of `~/.bashrc`.
- opening gnome-terminal with bash in the default non-login shell mode, with custom command `bash -x`.

Based on debug ouput, I observed that the `~/.bashrc` is the starting point of script sourcing. But the `$HOME/.local/bin` and `$HOME/bin` are already there in `PATH` even before that.

Comment: Tried running `sh -x` as the custom command? Which distro is this? What does `gnome-terminal-server`'s `PATH` containd?

Comment: Hi @muru, Sorry for the delayed response. I just tried `sh -x` as the custom command. Upon opening gonme-terminal, I didn't see anything get sourced. But, `echo $PATH` says that `$HOME/.local/bin` and `$HOME/bin` are there. I'm on Fedora 23. According to procfs, the parent `gnome-terminal-server` is PATH is `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin`. I'll update the question to include these information.

Comment: What about xterm, or xfce4-terminal?

Comment: @muru, I'm not sure what information you are asking. (I still have much to learn.) But in `sh -x` custom command environment,  `echo $TERM` outputs `xterm-256color`.

Comment: Well, I'm asking if you see this behaviour in another terminal emulator than GNOME Terminal, like xterm, or xfce4-terminal (or konsole, or terminator, or…). If you see this behaviour in them, we could eliminate GNOME Terminal as the source (and confirm it if none of those show this behaviour).

Comment: @muru, here is what I tried: I tried guake (configured to invoke `/bin/sh`), xterm (`Alt+F2`, then run `xterm /bin/sh`), xfce4-terminal (`Alt+F2`, then run `xfce4-terminal -e /bin/sh`). In all these terminals, `echo $PATH` output is consistent with that of gnome-terminal. Maybe it's somewhere else. :-(

Comment: @muru, I tried to invoke `python` as custom command to gnome-terminal, guake, xterm and xfce4-terminal, observing that `os.environ['PATH']` does contain these two user specific entries. Now I'm so confused.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, with the terminal `PATH` being initially set to `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin`.

Having checked all the usual suspects, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, I resorted to changing the `DefaultEnvironment` setting in both `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `/etc/systemd/user.conf`. But I still ended up with `/usr/local/...` in the `PATH`.

By chance I came across a reference to `pam_env` whilst trying to figure out where the path environment was being set. So I added the following line to `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`:

```
PATH DEFAULT=/bin:/sbin
```

After logging back in, the terminal shell `PATH` was then free of the pesky local paths.

I am pretty sure the defaults come from `pam_env`, as after changing the systemd configuration, neither PID 1 nor the `systemd --user` process has the local paths in the environment, but `gnome-terminal-server` did.

Modern Linux is becoming a configuration nightmare.

I realise this is not an answer to the OP's issue. But it seemed sufficiently related to be worth a mention.

Answer (score 1):

According to a comment on Fedora, *[Adding ~/.local/bin to default PATH](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2011-July/154901.html)*, this was a Fedora-specific change in the **bash** configuration, a few years ago.

The change was [made in the RPM](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/bash.git/diff/?id=02b20d810111e8b53bb98ad49fedd1d583ce62e1) (not upstream), and undocumented.

Comment: I do not think this is the case, as `~/.bash_profile` does not get sourced at all when bash is _not_ a login shell, nor does it get sourced in `sh`-compatible mode. However in both situations, `~/.local/bin` and `~/bin` are present in `PATH`.